# DateTime ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId isn't working

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I save time to UTC in database.

And I want convert time to local time zone when get time data from database.

Here is function.

```
    public static List<string> convertListDateTime(List<string> timelist, TimeZoneInfo local)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < timelist.Count; i++)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(timelist[i]);
            dt = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, local.Id);
            timelist[i] = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        }
        return timelist;
    }
```

timelist is string list that has data from database.

But timelist is not change. It is the same as the database data.

How can I do?

Comment: Store your datetime data, as datatime data in the database (not a string), would be my first suggestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first problem:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(timelist[i]);
```

You haven't said that the value *is* in UTC, so it's assumed to be in local time. A conversion from that to local time is a no-op. You can fix that when parsing by saying that the input is in UTC and you want the output to be in UTC too:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(
    timelist[i],
    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal | DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal);
```

But secondly, you should try to avoid all this string conversion anyway: if you store the values in the database as `DateTime` values instead of strings, that makes things a lot easier.

I would try to use the values *as* `DateTime` values as far as possible too - only convert to strings when you absolutely have to, and ideally *not* as part of an operation which is also performing time zone changes.

Finally, rather than using `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId`, if you've already got a `TimeZoneInfo` you can use that directly:

```
DateTime convertedValue = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(utcValue, zoneInfo);
```